# Convert external and internal styles into inline styles with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In order to make html content with styles more portable, I need to convert all external styles (`<link>` importing external .css) and internal styles (defined with `<style>`s) into the inline styles of the elements.

For example, if I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
<style>
.alert { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<div id="foo" class="special alert" style="font-size: 2em;">something</div>
```

and a common.css with:

```
.special { border: 1px solid dotted; }
```

I want a result like:

```
<div id="foo" class="special alert" style="border: 1px solid dotted; color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size: 2em;">something</div>
```

Currently the problem is how to get all external and internal styles that are applied to the div[#foo]?

Comment: What's the use case here? Is this to be a pre-processing step or at runtime?

Comment: My case is more likely a "post-process", i.e. to capture or to convert a webpage into other file schema or format, which could not allow external/internal styles.

Answer (score -1):

How many CSS properties do you have? if not so many, you can do something like $("#foo").css("border", "1px");

if there are a lot of CSS files, its always not suggested do inline style